# API only Ruby on Rails 5 implementing OAuth2 (preferably with devise and doorkeeper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, json-api, doorkeeper

I want to make a JSON API with Rails 5 that will feed an angular app and possibly later mobile apps. I do not want to include any html in the rails application. I typically use devise to handle user creation and authentication in regular rails apps. I would like to implement an OAuth2 compliant flow so I found a gem called doorkeeper.

I like devise as it handles the sending of a confirmation email and password reseting, etc. I would like doorkeeper to keep my app OAuth2 compliant.

My issue is that the OAuth2 documentation says to try to not use the password grant type but I cannot find a better alternative method for a site being served by the same server the API is coming from. Should I require a CSRF token only for the OAuth route to acquire the access token to ensure the request is coming from the site? Should I use the CSRF token from within the angular app the entire time in conjunction with the access token?

Also should I have devise handle the sending of the access token? How would that work in the other flows besides password grant? I would also have to edit devise to only accommodate JSON requests and to respond in kind.

Also I would like to implement a JWT however I still think it best to have the token linked to a session ID, I know the kind of defeats the purpose of the JWT but I think its beneficial to use the JWT in order to accommodate native apps.

I am sure this is not an uncommon thing to want to set up nowadays but I have yet to find a solid walkthrough connecting devise, doorkeeper, and an API only setup.  Has anyone experienced and implemented a something like this?

Comment: I would consider setting up doorkeeper as a seperate app - an authentication microservice. Mainly because doorkeeper renders HTML and requires middleware that is not needed in a pure API app.

Comment: For authentication in the API I would use Knock instead of Devise - its a much lighter weight alternative that is built solely for token based authentication. Devise is quite the do-every-possible-scenario bohemoth which is great for classical apps but not so much for an API application.

Comment: We wouldn't want to set doorkeeper up as a separate app since we don't want to send people away from the website to authenticate when its coming from the same server. Knock is a good alternative but do you know of any gems that would handle the part of sending password reset emails and email confirmations etc that devise currently handles well? @max

Comment: Having doorkeeper on a separate app does not need to be discernible to the user.

Comment: I’m not aware of gems any but it’s not really that complex to write from scratch. If anything it will be far simpler than the Devise code since you can make assumptions about the user class and implementation.

Comment: That's true, I just like implementing open source stuff to take advantage of updating rather than maintaining your own package. I guess I would like to know how a service like facebook operates. They are an OAuth2 provider however they also have their own site which validates which password credentials. I am not sure if they use an angular app for their site but if they did what would they do? @max